# UITableViewCell Delete button animation

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've noticed that in iOS8 default insertion/deletion control has a specific animation from top-left corner:
[image: delete text animation]

However in iOS9 that animation is gone.
Do you know anything about it? Has it changed between iOS versions indeed? Any way of customizing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is still there.

Check the attachment [right side left swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fml4j.png)

Comment: You haven't understand.
My problem is about "Delete" text. It animates enlarging from top left corner. In iOS 9 it does not.